# Basic query in unexpectedly slow in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am running a basic select on a table with 189,000 records.  The table structure is:

```
items

id - primary key
ad_count - int, indexed
company_id - varchar, indexed
timestamps
```

the select query is:

```
select * 
from `items` 
where `company_id` is not null 
    and `ad_count` <= 100 
order by `ad_count` desc, `items`.`id` asc 
limit 50
```

On my production servers, just the MySQL portion of the execution takes 300 - 400ms

If I run an `explain`, I get:

```
select type: SIMPLE 
table: items    
type: range 
possible_keys: items_company_id_index,items_ad_count_index  
key: items_company_id_index 
key_len: 403    
ref: NULL   
rows: 94735 
Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

When fetching this data in our application, we paginate it groups of 50, but the above query is "the first page"

I'm not too familiar with dissecting `explain` queries.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: you do not need your second sort, `items.id asc` I dont believe that will save you much time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ORDER BY clause with different sorting order can cause the creation of temporary tables and filesort. MySQL below (and including) v5.7 doesn't handle such scenarios well at all, and there is actually no point in indexing the fields in the ORDER BY clause, as MySQL's optimizer will never use them.
Therefore, if the application's requirements allow, it's best to use the same order for all columns in the ORDER BY clause.

So in this case:

```
order by `ad_count` desc, `items`.`id` asc
```

Will become:

```
order by `ad_count` desc, `items`.`id` desc
```

P.S, as a small tip to read more about - it seems that MySQL 8.0 is going to change things and these use cases might perform significantly better when it's released.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `items_company_id_index` with a multi-column index on `(company_id, ad_count)`.

```
DROP INDEX items_company_id_index ON items;
CREATE INDEX items_company_id_ad_count_index ON items (company_id, ad_count);
```

This will allow it to use the index to test both conditions in the `WHERE` clause. Currently, it's using the index just to find non-null `company_id`, and then doing a full scan of those records to test `ad_count`. If most records have non-null `company_id`, it's scanning most of the table.

You don't need to retain the old index on just the `company_id` column, because a multi-column index is also an index on any prefix columns, because of the way B-trees work.

Comment: company_id's condition in the WHERE clause is: "IS NOT NULL". Wouldn't that be a range scan? If so, I don't think there is a point to continue any further as the database won't be able to scan any further in the index (two ranges). I would consider to add an index on whichever has better possibility for filtering (either company_id or ad_count). Also, I would try to add an index on the ORDER BY clause (in addition, not instead) and let the optimizer choose between them.

Comment: Good point. If it were `IS NULL` it could use the index, but `IS NOT NULL` has to do a full scan of all the other indexes. It's surprising that it chose to use that index according to `EXPLAIN`. The `ORDER BY` column is already indexed.

Comment: Well, I don't think there is an index on both ORDER BY columns. Even if there were, it won't use it (at least not in full), as there is a mixed order used (ASC & DESC). @djt, if it makes sense logic-wise, having an index on both and changing the sort order to a constant one (both DESC or both ASC) will allow the optimizer to choose that index, potentially.

Comment: @TomShir as it turns out Tom, you were correct.  Ordering by 2 columns using both ASC and DESC caused the optimizer to use filesort.  Changing them to order in the same direction greatly reduced the query time.  Please add that as an answer for others and I'll be sure to accept it

Comment: @djt, thanks for the feedback, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here (depending on your sql version this could be faster) but try a Inner Join with your company table.

Like:

```
Select *
From items
INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id = items.company_id
 and items.ad_count <= 100
LIMIT 50;
```

because of your high indexcount building the btrees will slow down the database each time a new entry is inserted. Maybe remove the index of ad_count?! (this depends on how often you use that entry for queries)